# Rails, Jquery sortable saves the positions but in a wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, position, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a rails app where I implemented Jquery sortable and I would like to drag the pictures and save their positions in order. Actually it saves in order but at some point by itself it changes the order.

For example,

I have 16 picture and these pictures' positions are saved as expected, 1,2,3,4,..,16. But then after 10 mins later I see that all the positions are 166. But I do not know why this happened.

Here are the codes,

```
<Picture id: 4213, name: nil, car_id: 202, created_at: "2017-03-31 17:34:48", updated_at: "2018-03-09 14:01:34", image: "24.jpg", position: 2>, #<Picture id: 4220, name: nil, car_id: 202, created_at: "2017-03-31 17:35:00", updated_at: "2018-03-09 14:01:34", image: "30.jpg", position: 3>..
```

It saves like this from console;

```
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.139876 #65128] DEBUG -- :   CarGroup Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "car_groups".* FROM "car_groups" WHERE "car_groups"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "All"]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.142094 #65128] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2009]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.144736 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Car Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 202]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.148426 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8744]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.150712 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.157362 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.153131"], ["id", 8744]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.159729 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 1)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.163624 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'

D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.166731 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ("pictures"."position" + 1), "updated_at" = '2018-03-09 14:16:02.165233' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures".id != 8744) AND ("pictures"."position" >= 1) AND ("pictures"."position" < 422)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.180802 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (13.0ms)  commit transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.182507 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8746]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.183784 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.186040 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 2], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.184761"], ["id", 8746]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.187173 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 2)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.189225 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'

D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.195676 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (3.9ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ("pictures"."position" + 1), "updated_at" = '2018-03-09 14:16:02.190611' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures".id != 8746) AND ("pictures"."position" >= 2) AND ("pictures"."position" < 424)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.201104 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (4.2ms)  commit transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.202869 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8745]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.204345 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.211590 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (3.1ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 3], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.206634"], ["id", 8745]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.214258 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 3)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.217133 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'

D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.220316 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ("pictures"."position" + 1), "updated_at" = '2018-03-09 14:16:02.218177' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures".id != 8745) AND ("pictures"."position" >= 3) AND ("pictures"."position" < 424)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.228284 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (4.2ms)  commit transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.230440 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8747]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.232011 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.234995 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 4], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.233093"], ["id", 8747]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.236920 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 4)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.239218 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'

D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.242578 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ("pictures"."position" + 1), "updated_at" = '2018-03-09 14:16:02.240491' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures".id != 8747) AND ("pictures"."position" >= 4) AND ("pictures"."position" < 425)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.248459 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (4.6ms)  commit transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.250204 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8748]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.251196 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.254066 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 5], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.251964"], ["id", 8748]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.255436 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 5)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.257680 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'

D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.263112 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.9ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ("pictures"."position" + 1), "updated_at" = '2018-03-09 14:16:02.259977' WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures".id != 8748) AND ("pictures"."position" >= 5) AND ("pictures"."position" < 426)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.269877 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (5.7ms)  commit transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.271924 #65128] DEBUG -- :   Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."car_id" = ? AND "pictures"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["car_id", 202], ["id", 8749]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.273540 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  begin transaction
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.278737 #65128] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "pictures" SET "position" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "pictures"."id" = ?  [["position", 6], ["updated_at", "2018-03-09 14:16:02.274866"], ["id", 8749]]
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.281097 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE (1 = 1) AND ("pictures"."position" = 6)
D, [2018-03-09T17:16:02.284165 #65128] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)              SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT sql
            FROM sqlite_temp_master
            WHERE name='index_pictures_on_car_id' AND type='index'
```

This is how I get, the positions and controller action;

```
Parameters: {"pic"=>["8744", "8746", "8745", "8747", "8748", "8749", "8750", "8751", "8752", "8753", "8754", "8755", "8756", "8757", "8758", "8759", "8760", "8761", "8762", "8763", "8764", "8765", "8766", "8767", "8768", "8769", "8770", "8771", "8772", "8773", "8774", "8775", "8776", "8777", "8778", "8779", "8780", "8781", "8782", "8783", "8784", "8785", "8786", "8787", "8788", "8789", "8790", "8791", "8792", "8793"], "locale"=>"tr", "car_id"=>"202"}

def sort
    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
    params[:pic].each_with_index do |id, index|
      #@car.pictures.where(id: id).update_all(position: index+1)
      pict = @car.pictures.where(id: id).first 
      pict.position = index + 1
      pict.save
    end
  render nothing: true

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list gem to implement this.